# Regular expression to check if number is 3 or 6 digit hex

Tags: javascript, regex

I already have this regular expression:

```
function check(){
    var re = /[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;
    var inputString = document.getElementById("check").value;

    if(re.test(inputString)) {
         window.alert("Valid hex colour")
    } else {
         window.alert("Invalid hex colour")
    }

    re.lastIndex = 0;
}
```

And this is the input:

```
<input id="check" maxlength="6" placeholder="------">
```

This is the event listener:

```
document.getElementById('check').onkeydown=function(cc){
            if(cc.keyCode==13){
                check()
            }
            else if(cc.keyCode==46){
                document.getElementById("check").value = "";
            }
        }
```

This works fine. I also tried this regular expression:

```
/[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;
```

But this also accepts hex values that are 3, 4, 5 or 6 characters long.
How can you check for hex values that are exactly 3 or exactly 6 characters long using a regular expression? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to match a whole string? `/^([0-9A-Fa-f]{3}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{6})$/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This works fine. I also tried this regular expression:
>
> ```
> /[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/g;
> ```
>
> But this also accepts hex values that are 3, 4, 5 or 6 characters long.

You need anchors (and no global flag):

```
/^(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{3}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{6})$/
```

You can also add `i` to make it less verbose:

```
/^(?:[0-9A-F]{3}|[0-9A-F]{6})$/i
```

Without anchors, a four-digit hex string matches the `{3}` rule (since it *contains* a three-digit hex string).